# How to get JSON from System.Windows.Browser.ScriptObject

Tags: silverlight, json, silverlight-3.0

I being passed a object from javascript as JSON and it's type in Silverlight is of type `System.Windows.Browser.ScriptObject`.

How do I get the JSON representation from the script object?

Cheers

AWC

Answer (score -1):

There is no native support for this in Silverlight. [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) supports Silverlight though.

Comment: I suggest you go look at the System.Json namespace before answering!

Comment: I may well be wrong (it wouldn't be the first time) but my understanding is that System.Json provides a parser to convert from a JSON string to a nicer object model. It doesn't support serializing an object to a string. If I am wrong, please post an answer to your own question.